# Constraint for restricting use to choose only one country, but multiple states

Tags: java, jpa

I'm trying to create Entities for the following:

> **State**
>
> -stateId (Auto Generated)
>
> -stateName (Not Null)
>
> -countryId (Foreign Key)
>
> **Country**
>
> -countryId (Auto Generated)
>
> -countryName (Not Null)
>
> **User**
>
> -userId (Auto Generated)
>
> -firstName (Not Null)
>
> -lastName (Not Null)
>
> -List Of **State** (ManyToMany)

My Requirement is that the user can enter states from only one country. How do I attain this? I was able to create entities for the above stated but I cannot figure out how to implement the constraint for only one country.

Comment: Before adding a writing the new state for the user to db you need to get one state (underlying the assumption that your data is consistent according to the business view: one country per user) and check if the state he wants to enter is in the same country.
If you have many, many states you may want to maintain a countryId at the user.

Comment: That logic would mainly be on my service side. I was trying to implement the same with Database constraints. Would that be possible?

Comment: What is the DB you are using? Am I right this is an entity model you already modeled in an DB? What about an insert trigger?

Comment: I'm working with **PostgreSQL**. And Yeah, I'd already modeled the same in DB. I was trying to figure out the same using entities only avoiding any additional work on the DB or Service Side.